# Excel file become corrupted and remove existing data validation when workbook created from original file with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I need to write data to existing excel workbook (.xls) but when the workbook is created, it become corrupted with error `We found a problem with some content in...`. When yes is clicked, the excel workbook lost some of the formula and the cell style.

The excel file is protected and cannot change anything in the sheet that contains the data validation list.

There are two cells with data validation list. The first one has list of 54 items and the second one has list of 229 items and the format is custom date. The validation data list is pre-existing and protected, so cannot change anything in the sheet.

Is there any workaround can be done? I cannot change any other thing to the excel except for write the data to the unprotected cell using the java code.

This is test code that I use:

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("D:/Test/Test.xls");
Workbook wb = null;
wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInput);

fileInput.close();

Sheet sheet = null;
Cell cell = null;

sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);

cell = sheet.getRow(10).getCell(2);

cell.setCellValue("10.00");

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/Out/Test_Updated.xls");
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: The issue is not reproducible from this vague problem description. To be able to reproduce, one would need the `*.xls` file and the code used and the information what Apache POI version used.

Comment: Hi Axel, sorry if the problem description is too vague, I have updated with part of code I use to write in the excel, the sheet contains the data validation list is supposedly to not be changed which is index 0, the code only writes to sheet index 1 and the `*.xls` file is protected with password. Is it easier if i were able to provide the `*.xls` file?

Comment: The code alone will not help. Unless cell `C11`, which gets changed is part of something special and not simply a data cell. See my first comment. There I told what would be needed.

Comment: The Apache POI version used is 3.15 beta 1, for the test excel file, where do I pass it? Sorry for this kind of question because I rarely ask any questions on this site.

Comment: This site does not provide file storage. You need upload it to some public available file storage. But be aware uploading files containing secret data. Correct way is to create a file containing only test data but nevertheless produces the issue. That's your task. Else hire a specialist and put confidentiality obligation in the contract.